# Suppose that $X$ is a real orthogonal matrix and $D$ is a real diagonal matrix (entries of $D$ are not distinct) such that $D=X^{-1}DX$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $X$ is a real orthogonal matrix and $D$ is a real diagonal matrix (entries of $D$ are not distinct) such that $D=X^{-1}DX$. Can we explicitly obtain $X$ or can we say that $X$ is always a permutation matrix? If $D$ has distinct entries, then I know that $X$ is a diagonal matrix with entries belong to $\{1,-1\}$

Comment: What if $D=I$, the identity matrix?

Comment: If $D=I$ then any orthogonal matrix will do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entries on the diagonal of $D$ are not distinct, then you have infinitely many choices for $X$: if $D=\begin{bmatrix} aI_m & 0 \\ 0 & bI_n \end{bmatrix}$, with $a\neq b$, then the condition $XD = DX$ is equivalent to $X=\begin{bmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & B \end{bmatrix}$ for some square matrices $A$ and $B$. Such a matrix $X$ is orthogonal if and only if the matrices $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal. If one of $m$ or $n$ is at least 2 (repeated entries), then there are infinitely many choices for the corresponding matrix, and hence for $X$. [That can be extended to having more than two distinct values on the diagonal of $D$.]